# fetching google images through html dom parser

Tags: php, image, dom

I want to fetch images from goolge/images again any query. I am using following code but having no result. count always return zero.

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
        $html=file_get_html('http://www.google.com.pk/images?q='.$_GET['q']);
        $find=$html->find('ul.rg_ul li');
        echo(count($find));
```

First i want to get all li tags from ul.rg_ul. But it always return zero. what is wrong with it. i am totally stuck on this. I have even tried

```
$find=$html->find('a.rg_l img');
```

but result is always zero

Comment: You can't use multiple css selectors AFAIK. Use `$list=array();foreach($html->find('ul.rg_ul') as $i) $list[]=$i->find('li'); print_r($list);`

Comment: Thanks Jason. But this is also returning empty array

Comment: Do a var_dump($html); IIRC google sometimes does not like it when you access their pages via this type of method (via a script that scrapes their pages) and they will return a blank page or some kind of error.

Comment: @Daniel Doezema it is also empty

Comment: That's the reason then. Google is detecting your method of access via some criteria and not outputting the HTML for you to scrape. Just to be sure try a var_dump(file_get_contents('http://www.google.com.pk/images?q='.$_GET['q'])); in the script.

Comment: no Daniel when i simple echo($html) it results me whole page. But when i want to access some of the tag, ul,li,a it is returning zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last found solution by self learning and researching after receiving no response. Google doesn't support the method which i was using. Google provides its [API](http://code.google.com/apis/websearch/docs/#fonje_snippets) to fetch the images. But I have done it by a [mini google bot](http://www.barattalo.it/2010/03/30/php-google-images-mini-bot/). Now any one who is facing problem can get advantage from here :P